# How to add values in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have got a projeect with react native. It counst trains of user:[image]
Also, when the user make regisration, it takes the standart value - 0:

```
          set(ref(db, 'users/' + res.data.localId), {          
            email: email,
            countTrains: 0
          }).then(() => {
             console.log('Made new account');    
        })  
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

And when i try to add a new value into my countTrains variable:

```
update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
      countTrains: +countTrain, // may the mistake is here
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Обновление бд');    
  })  
      .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
      });
```

But if a make a logout and takes it again, my value becomes to again 1:[image]

**I need to add value like 4 + 1, and in the firebase should be 5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment a value in the database, use the [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) operator:

```
update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
  countTrains: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(4);
})
```

If you're using the v9 modular SDK, that'd be:

```
update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
  countTrains: increment(4);
})
```